# Bash - How to check if an id string in one file is in an id range policy in another file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

After a long search with no success, I've come here for some help. I have two files:
a.txt - contains a list of id strings
b.txt - contains a list of id range policies

For instance:

a.txt:

```
AC0359
AC0360
AC0361
AC0362
AC0369
AC0372
AC0374
AC0376
AC0380
BD0381
BD0384
BD0386
BD0389
BD0390
BD0392
BD0393
EF0394
EF0395
EF0398
EF0402
EF0404
EF0409
EF0410
```

b.txt:

```
from="AC0000" to="AC0400"
from="BD0300" to="BD0700"
from="EF0400" to="EF1000"
from="GT0000" to="GT2700"
```

I would like to know for each of the id strings listed in a.txt, if it is within one of the range policies listed in b.txt. I have been trying to find a solution to this for quite some time, so I really appreciate the help.

This is what I have done so far:

```
found_range=false
while read barcode; do
    while read range_line <&3; do
        if [[ $range_line == from=* && $found_range = false ]]
        then
            start_range=$(echo $range_line | cut -d '"' -f 2);
            end_range=$(echo $range_line | cut -d '"' -f 4);
            if [[ ! "$barcode" < "$start_range" && ! "$barcode" > "$end_range" ]]
            then
                echo "$barcode is between the range $start_range and $end_range"
            fi
        fi
    done 3<b.txt
done <a.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try making a solution yourself ?

Comment: Yes I did try, but I'm pretty new to bash scripting and my attempts to solve this haven't worked. I tried reading each line from a.txt and saving it into a variable $rec. For every $rec I used 'grep' to find policies that start with the same id prefix in b.txt. However, I understand that reading from two separate files in the same iteration could be problematic and I suspect my id comparisons are failing either because of this or because i am not comparing the id with the range properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, my solution is in the edited answer.